# How do I automatically replace a large .xml database file from a website with a newer file each month?

Tags: python, xml, database

I am working on a project right now that uses data from a large xml database file (usually like 8gb) pulled from a website. The website updates this database file monthly, so every month, there's a newer and more accurate database file.

I started my project about a year ago, so it is using a database file from February 2019. For the sake of people using my program, I would like for the database file to be replaced with the new one from each month when that gets rolled out.

How could I go about implementing this in my project so I don't have to manually go and replace the file with a newer one each month? Is it something I should write into the program? But, if that's the case, it would only update when the program is ran. Or, is there a way to have some script do this that automatically checks once a month?

Note: this project is not being used by people yet, it has got a long way to go, but I am trying to figure out how to implement these features earlier on before I get to a point where I can publish it.

Answer (score 0):

I would first find out if there is an API built on top of that XML data that you could leverage, instead of downloading the XML into your own website. That way you always get the latest version of the data, since you're pulling it on-demand.

However, an on-demand integration wouldn't be a good idea if you would be hitting the API with any kind of heavy frequency, or if you would be pulling large datasets from said API. In that case, you need an ETL integration. Look into open-source ETL tools (just Google it) to help move that data in an automated fashion; I would recommend importing the XML into MongoDB or some other DB, and pull the data from there instead of reading it from a flat file.

And if you absolutely have to have it as a flat file, looking into using Gatsby; it's a framework for static websites that need to be reconstituted every once in a while.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will look into that. I actually had used the API at first, but it had some limitations that were frustrating. For instance, the API wouldn't be able to retrieve more than about 200 pages from a given search. What I want to do with my program is to be able to use every item in a search, instead of being limited by the first x amount of pages.